# How to clear cache in Cordova/Phonegap app (without removing localstorage)

Tags: javascript, cordova, caching, phonegap

I have a `Cordova` app and I noticed that its size is increasing every time I navigate the section where there are many images (links from web and not stored on the device).

I think that the reason is that I need to clear webview cache (I use `Crosswalk` so the webview is based on `chromium`).

I search around but I can't find a way to clear only cache every time user exits the app.
I tried to run `window.location.reload(true)` on exit but it does not work.

Besides, I have found some plugins that do the job, but they remove all storage data (`localstorage` too) and I don't want that.

Could you help me with that?

Thanks

Comment: Try https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-cache

Comment: @HarishKommuri, I have tried it, but unfortunately it removes localstorage too.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?